# Matlab NaN and Inf issue

Tags: matlab, nan, infinity

So, I'm implementing the EM algorithm in Matlab, but my matrices quickly end up contaminated by `NaN` and `Inf` values. I think it might be caused by matrix inversions, but I'm not sure that's the only reason.

Here is the code:

```
function [F, Q, R, x_T, P_T] = em_algo(y, G)
    % y_t = G_t'*x_t + v_t    1*1 = 1*p p*1
    % x_t = F*x_t-1 + w_t     p*1 = p*p p*1
    % G is T*p
    p = size(G,2); % p = nb assets ; G = T*p
    q = size(y,2); % q = nb observations ; y = T*q
    T = size(y,1); % y is T*1
    F = eye(p); % = Transition matrix  p*p 
    Q = eye(p); % innovation (v) covariance matrix p*p
    R = eye(q); % noise (w) covariance matrix q x q
    x_T_old = zeros(p,T);
    mu0 = zeros(p,1);
    Sigma = eye(p); % Initial state covariance matrix p*p
    converged = 0;
    i = 0;
    max_iter = 60; % only for testing purposes
    while ~converged
        if i > max_iter
            break;
        end
        % E step = smoothing
        fprintf('Iteration %d\n',i);
        [x_T,P_T,P_Tm2] = smoother(G,F,Q,R,mu0,Sigma,y);
        %x_T

        % M step 
        A = zeros(p,p);
        B = zeros(p,p);
        C = zeros(p,p);
        R = eye(q);

        for t = 2:T % eq (9) in EM paper
            A = A + (P_T(:,:,t-1) + (x_T(:,t-1)*x_T(:,t-1)'));
        end

        for t = 2:T % eq (10)
            %B = B + (P_Tm2(:,:,t-1) + (x_T(:,t)*x_T(:,t-1)'));
            B = B + (P_Tm2(:,:,t) + (x_T(:,t)*x_T(:,t-1)'));
        end

        for t = 1:T %eq (11)
            C = C + (P_T(:,:,t) + (x_T(:,t)*x_T(:,t)'));
        end    

        F = B*inv(A); %eq (12)
        Q = (1/T)*(C - (B*inv(A)*B')); % eq (13)  pxp 

        for t = 1:T
            bias = y(t) - (G(t,:)*x_T(:,t));
            R = R + ((bias*bias') + (G(t,:)*P_T(:,:,t)*G(t,:)'));
        end
        R = (1/T)*R;

        if i>1            
            err = norm(x_T-x_T_old)/norm(x_T_old);
            if err < 1e-4
                converged = 1;
            end            
        end  
        x_T_old = x_T;
        i = i+1;
    end
    fprintf('EM algorithm iterated %d times\n',i);
end
```

This iterates until convergence (which never happens due to my issue) and calls `smoother.m` at each iteration:

```
function [x_T, P_T, P_Tm2] = smoother(G,F,Q,R,mu0,Sigma,y)
    % G is T*p
    p = size(mu0,1); % mu0 is p*1
    T = size(y,1); % y is T*1
    J = zeros(p,p,T);
    K = zeros(p,T); % gain matrix
    x = zeros(p,T);
    x(:,1) = mu0;
    x_m1 = zeros(p,T);
    x_T = zeros(p,T); % x values when we know all the data
    % Notation : x = xt given t ; x_m1 = xt given t-1 (m1 stands for minus
    % one)
    P = zeros(p,p,T);% array of cov(xt|y1...yt), eq (6) in Shumway & Stoffer 1982
    P(:,:,1) = Sigma;
    P_m1 = zeros(p,p,T); % Same notation ; = cov(xt, xt-1|y1...yt) , eq (7)
    P_T = zeros(p,p,T);
    P_Tm2 = zeros(p,p,T); % cov(xT, xT-1|y1...yT)

    for t = 2:T %starts at t = 2 because at each time t we need info about t-1
        x_m1(:,t) = F*x(:,t-1); % eq A3 ; pxp * px1 = px1
        P_m1(:,:,t) = (F*P(:,:,t-1)*F') + Q; % A4 ; pxp * pxp = pxp

        if nnz(isnan(P_m1(:,:,t)))
            error('NaNs in P_m1 at time t = %d',t);
        end
        if nnz(isinf(P_m1(:,:,t)))
            error('Infs in P_m1 at time t = %d',t);
        end

        K(:,t) = P_m1(:,:,t)*G(t,:)'*pinv((G(t,:)*P_m1(:,:,t)*G(t,:)') + R); %A5 ; pxp * px1 * 1*1 = p*1
        %K(:,t) = P_m1(:,:,t)*G(t,:)'/((G(t,:)*P_m1(:,:,t)*G(t,:)') + R); %A5 ; pxp * px1 * 1*1 = p*1

        % The matrix inversion seems to generate NaN values which quickly
        % contaminate all the other matrices. There is no warning about
        % (close to) singular matrices or whatever. The use of pinv()
        % instead of inv() seems to solve the problem... but I don't think
        % it's the appropriate way to deal with it, there must be something
        % wrong elsewhere

        if nnz(isnan(K(:,t)))
            error('NaNs in K at time t = %d',t);
        end


        x(:,t) = x_m1(:,t) + (K(:,t)*(y(t)-(G(t,:)*x_m1(:,t)))); %A6
        P(:,:,t) = P_m1(:,:,t) - (K(:,t)*G(t,:)*P_m1(:,:,t)); %A7
    end

    x_T(:,T) = x(:,T);
    P_T(:,:,T) = P(:,:,T);

    for t = T:-1:2 % we stop at 2 since we need to use t-1
        %P_m1 seem to get really huge (x10^22...), might lead to "Inf"
        %values which in turn might screw pinv()

        %% inv() caused NaN value to appear, pinv seems to solve the issue

        J(:,:,t-1) = P(:,:,t-1)*F'*pinv(P_m1(:,:,t)); % A8 pxp * pxp * pxp  
        %J(:,:,t-1) = P(:,:,t-1)*F'/(P_m1(:,:,t)); % A8 pxp * pxp * pxp  
        x_T(:,t-1) = x(:,t-1) + J(:,:,t-1)*(x_T(:,t)-(F*x(:,t-1))); %A9  % Becomes NaN during 8th iteration!
        P_T(:,:,t-1) = P(:,:,t-1) + J(:,:,t-1)*(P_T(:,:,t)-P_m1(:,:,t))*J(:,:,t-1)'; %A10

        nans = [nnz(isnan(J)) nnz(isnan(P_m1)) nnz(isnan(F)) nnz(isnan(x_T)) nnz(isnan(x_m1))];  
        if nnz(nans)
            error('NaN invasion at time t = %d',t);
        end
    end

    P_Tm2(:,:,T) = (eye(p) - K(:,T)*G(T,:))*F*P(:,:,T-1); % %A12

    for t = T:-1:3 % stop at 3 because use of t-2
       P_Tm2(:,:,t-1) = P_m1(:,:,t-1)*J(:,:,t-2)' + J(:,:,t-1)*(P_Tm2(:,:,t)-F*P(:,:,t-1))*J(:,:,t-2)'; % A11
    end
end
```

The `NaN`s and `Inf`s start popping around the ~8<sup>th</sup> iteration.

I guess in there somewhere I'm doing something unholy with my matrices, but I really have no clue about what's wrong. I trust your expertise.

Thanks in advance for the help.

---

Rody :
Here is how I generate the data (it's not "real world" data yet, just some test data generated to check that nothing goes wront) :

```
T = 500;
nbassets = 3;
G = .1 + randn(T,nbassets); % random walk trajectories
y = (1:T).';
y = 1.01.^y; % 1 * T % Exponential 1% returns curve
```

Dan :
You're right. I indeed lack the math background to really understand how the formulas are derived. I know it doesn't help, but I'm not sure I can remedy that for the time being. :/

---

Rody : Yes indeed, I arrived at the same conclusion. But I really have no clue what makes it go wrong like that.

Here is a link to the paper :
http://www.stat.pitt.edu/stoffer/em.pdf

The formulas for the smoother are all at the very end, in the appendix. Thanks for your time so far.

Comment: You can and should embed code directly in your question.

Comment: You may want to run it with `dbstop if naninf`
That way you can quickly see when it happens for the first time and trackback why it happens.

Comment: While editing your question I saw an `inv(A)` pop by a few times. Never, *never*, **never**, ***NEVER*** ever use `inv()` directly!! It's slow, inaccurate, not robust, etc. etc. Use `LU` decomposition and/or the backslash operator.

Comment: Can you give example inputs `y` and `G`?

Comment: Dennis' advice is very good. But the comment in your code "inv() caused NaN value to appear, pinv seems to solve the issue" is a big red flag that you don't really understand what this code and/or algorithm is doing (nothing wrong with that, happens to us all!). So my advice would be to step back and think about what this algorithm is supposed to be doing, and what the purpose of the matrix inversion is. Some extra thinking may be all that is required to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

As the user appears to have inserted the answer into his question I will post it here:

As mentioned by @Rody the cause of the problem was that the use of `inv` created `NaN` or `Inf` values.

The user 'solved' this by using `pinv` instead.